# how to prepopulate target in Primefaces picklist?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, picklist

How to populate the target in Primefaces picklist? I googled it but i didn't find any example related to this which help my requirement.

I have list of players which is already selected and unassigned. I want to use picklist. Source display the unassigned and target will show the selected one. Admin can make selected player unassigned (target->source) and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the showcase which zargarf mentioned is quite enough to populate the target. If you look over the constructor of the bean, there are sources populated. In the same way you can populate the targets.

Currently in the constructor is :

```
  //Players  
    List<Player> source = new ArrayList<Player>();  
    List<Player> target = new ArrayList<Player>();  

    source.add(new Player("Messi", 10, "messi.jpg"));  
    source.add(new Player("Iniesta", 8, "iniesta.jpg"));  
    source.add(new Player("Villa", 7, "villa.jpg"));  
    source.add(new Player("Alves", 2, "alves.jpg"));  
    source.add(new Player("Xavi", 6, "xavi.jpg"));  
    source.add(new Player("Puyol", 5, "puyol.jpg"));      

    players = new DualListModel<Player>(source, target);
```

Do in the same way with the target. `target.add(...)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @loan.  Got it.. Why there is no such good documentation in JSF :) .

Answer (score 1):

Follow the example on the showcase:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf

If you need to only show either target or source control arrows based on user role then you can bind showSourceControls and showTargetControls to a method in the managedbean that returns a string of "true" or "false" depending on the user role

Comment: This example show the population of source only, not the target. There is no relation of user role with this question. Thanks for the reply..

Comment: The picklist is bound to a DualListModel object. This has a source list and a target list within it. You can prepopulate the target list when creating your DualListModel obkect. Look at the backing bean for the example in the showcase

Answer (score 0):

add belwo code

```
 citiesTarget.add("Value1");
  citiesTarget.add("value2");
```